# RGB to ARGB conversion in Android

Tags: android, colors

I have RGB code for a color. For example Gray color (118,118,118). How can I use it in [setPixel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel%28int,%20int,%20int%29) function? Because setPixel() function wants argb for color.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
int color = Color.argb(255, 118, 118, 188);
```

if you want full opacity.

Answer (score 6):

The first (a) value represents the Alpha channel, or in plain language: the transparency. (How much you can see *through* this colour, to the images behind it)

The value is one byte, so acceptable values range from 0 to 255.

As per the answer above, a value of 255 means your colour will be completely opaque (solid).
A value of 128 will give you 50% transparency.
A value of 0 will make your object completely invisible, regardless of your colour value, but the object still exists, like a sheet of perfectly clear glass, if you allow the analogy.

This can be useful for e.g secret/hidden/invisible buttons, creating easter eggs, or specific cases of UI tuning.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call

```
@ColorInt int
argb= Color.rgb(118, 118, 118)
```

> Return a color-int from red, green, blue components.
>
> The alpha component is implicitly 255 (fully opaque)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#rgb(int,%20int,%20int)